# Conditionally Enabling Nix within a Stack Project Depending on Whether You're Running NixOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

When running stack on a NixOS laptop, I require

```
nix:
  enable: true
```

in my `stack.yaml` for it to work.

**Problem:** When I run `stack` within a project on a non-NixOS laptop, this generates an error.

**Question:** Is there a way for `stack.yaml` to conditionally enable nix if and only if you are running NixOS?

Comment: I would set `alias stack='stack --nix'` in `.bashrc` on the machine running NixOS and leave the `stack.yaml` nix-free.

Answer (score 1):

The `stack.yaml` file can not contain the logic you're requesting, but you can solve the problem by moving it into the user-specific or machine-specific config files, `~/.stack/config.yaml` or `/etc/stack/config.yaml`:

```
nix:
  enable: true
```

This will then be the default on your machine/user, so you can leave out the `nix/enable` flag from the project-specific `stack.yaml`.